# Lua C API: pushing function with lua_pushcfunction isn't working

Tags: c, api, lua

How can I define such a Lua function using C API?

```
function Caller(f)
    f()
end
```

This is what I've tried but it crashes:

```
typedef lua_CFunction luaFunc;

int Caller(lua_State* luaVM)
    luaFunc Func = lua_tocfunction(luaVM, 1);

    lua_pushcfunction(luaVM, Func);
    lua_call(luaVM, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value did you pass to `Caller`?  It must be C function, not Lua function.

Comment: Remove `lua_tocfunction` and `lua_pushcfunction` lines from your function to be able to call any argument passed into `Caller`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of the Lua code

```
function Caller(f)
    f()
end
```

is

```
int Caller(lua_State* luaVM)    
    lua_call(luaVM, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but it should be looked like as following:
in c functions

```
{
    ...
    lua_getglobal(luaVM, "Caller");
    lua_pushcfunction(luaVM, CallbackFunction)
    lua_call(luaVM, 0, 0)
    ...
}

int CallbackFunction(lua_State* luaVM)
{
    ...
}
```